# Deezer API 403 forbidden error when fetching a track by id?

Tags: reactjs, api

I want to access a song's info by using its own trackid on deezer. this is the react code:

```
fetch(
      `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.deezer.com/track/${songid}`
    )
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw Error("error");
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setTrackInfo(data);
        console.log(data);
      });
```

but i get a 403 forbidden error. i was adviced to add https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com because i was getting a cors error plus i know some deezer api endpoints need an access token but this one is public so it should be fine. how can i fix it?